# Fetch result of query twice

Tags: 7, database

I faced with problem while fetching query results, my code:

```
$result = $query->execute();
$array1 = $result->fetchAllKeyed(1, 0);
$array2 = $result->fetchAllKeyed(2, 0);
```

But the `$array2` is empty, so `fetchAllKeyed` cut all values from `$result`.

I'm already tried to use the following:

```
$query2 = clone $query;
$result = $query->execute();
$result2 = $query2->execute();
$array1 = $result->fetchAllKeyed(1, 0);
$array2 = $result2->fetchAllKeyed(2, 0);
```

It's works, but I don't want do two queries instead of one.

So, how can I do two (or more) different "fetch" from one result?

Comment: Did try duplicating the `$result` directly instead of recreating the query? `$result2 = $result` and then fetching the keys?

Comment: Doesn't works too.

If I use `$result2 = $result;` - I get empty fetch result.

If I use `$result2 = clone $result;` - the same.

Comment: Hmm, then I guess you'll have to use fetchAssoc() wich gets you an array of objects and then use a foreach loop to generate the 2 sub arrays. Seems like the only solution.

Answer (score 1):

Since fetchAllKeyed() internally uses foreach loop to sort the data, the answer given by  [Suranga Panagamuwa Gamage](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/41574/suranga-panagamuwa-gamage) to use fetchAssoc() and then a loop seems the most efficient way.